Cython struct with list attribute
I am trying to make a struct in Cython which has a list as a member. This is not allowed, since when I try to compile:
cdef struct CloseValues:
    int size
    list values
    list ks

I get the error C struct/union member cannot be a Python object.
Is there a C/Cpp alternative for this, which is also efficient and can be defined without specifying its size?

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you'd like to have, but I guess std::vector in C++ is the default equivalent of a Python list (except that it takes only one type; please tell us if you want to have a container that can take any type for its elements).
